# how to trigger modal when a input clicked?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

i want trigger bootstrap modal when i click in the text input, how can i do this with jquery?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
```

```
<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which text input? What have you tried? Use `$('#myModal').modal('show');` to display the modal

Comment: @Mivaweb yes , thanks . i found it, $("#myModal").modal()

Answer (score 8):

You can just use the data attributes as well, no extra jQuery needed. Though I don't think it will be triggered if the user tabs into the input vs. clicking into it.

```
<input type="text" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/bjup5787/)

> Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set data-toggle="modal" on a controller element, like a button, along with a data-target="#foo" or href="#foo" to target a specific modal to toggle.

Comment: This is so far the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".someInputClass").click(function(){
    $(".modal-content").modal("show");
})
```

Comment: While the above is by no means wrong - at all - it is generally advisable to bind events to the document, and delegate it to the element(s) you want to listen for that event. Eg: `$(document).on("click", "#someElement", function(e){
  // xxx
});` The benefit of this is that you can bind an event once, and affect multiple elements based on extra parameters passed with the event. It also makes for a leaner code base. It also allows you to bind to elements that may not yet be in the DOM.

Comment: @SimonDowdles i want after click on input the modal trigger and then from modal send back some value to the input again , what's the best for this?

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy - What data will be sent back to the input? Will it be data based on something the user selects inside the modal?

Comment: @SimonDowdles yes and i think i got it. thank u for ur attention

Answer (score 1):

Or with focus, in case the input is tabbed to, like

```
$(".someInputClass").focus(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
jQuery("input or inputid").on("input",function(){   
    jQuery("#myModal).modal('show);  
});
```